# Fix URL to return dropdownlist items with JsonResult - MVC- C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, jsonresult

My js dropdown code:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddDivision").change(function () {
        $.get("GetDepartment", { id: $("#ddDivision").val() }, function (data) {
              $("#ddDept").empty();
              $("#ddDept").append("<option value='Please Select'>Please Select</option>")
              $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                  console.log(row);
                  $("#ddDept").append("<option value='" + row.Value + "'>" + row.Text + "</option>")
              });
          });
      })
  });
```

The JsonResult that returns the list:

```
      public JsonResult GetDepartment(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //query to return items
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The error I get (the dropdown does not populate) but I get this in F12 dev tools:

http://localhost/Home/EditView/GetDepartment?id=2

So the URL is wrong, because its on EditView, it should return GetDepartment list, but it doesnt. How do I fix the URL ?

When I'm on the Index view, it returns the correct URL like Home/GetDepartment - how to fix this when using another view?

Also to mention, I use one controller, HomeController.

Comment: use the complete url instead of only method name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this problem of urls.

### Way 1:

Normally the recommended approach is to use the `Url.Action` helper method which makes sure to generate the correct url for the specified controller and action like:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetDepartment","Home")', { id: $("#ddDivision").val() }, function (data)
```

### Way 2:

and if the js code is in a separate js file then what we do is use data attributes of html elements like:

```
<select id="ddlDivision" data-url='@Url.Action("GetDepartment","Home")'>
```

and then in js what we can do is to use that url from data- attributes like below:

```
 $("#ddDivision").change(function () {
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    $.get(url , { id: $("#ddDivision").val() }, function (data) {
```

Hope it gives you idea of either way.

Comment: Thanks, this worked 100%. I learned something new. $.get('@Url.Action("GetDepartment","Home")' - Did not know this was the way to go.

Comment: @someone13 it recommended approach instead of using magic strings and it saves from expected failures when deployed at iis server is sub-directories

Comment: Hi Ehsan - it works on localhost, but not when I publish it to the IIS server? Does this Stay the same: $.get('@Url.Action("GetDepartment","Home")', { id: $("#ddDivision").val() }, function (data)

Comment: Yes it should work on published version too, check what is the url generated for published version browser debug tools

Comment: Nevermind, I used the incorrect dropdown ids. It works. THanks again!